# php simple encode decode function using only (0-9 A-Z a-z)

Tags: php, encryption

I'm setting up a PHP email tracking system that uses url parameters to track link click throughs.  Something like:

www.example.com?trackToken=10

I'm looking for a simple PHP encode / decode function I can put in place that will take a number (in this case 10) and convert in to strictly to number and letters.  something like:

www.example.com?trackToken=7aj8nG93nDpw9M9Nk1

I have found several variations of encrypt / decrypt functions using mcrypt.  However, the encrypted output always ends up containing strange characters.  These strange characters make it hard for my email messages to be sent/delivered.

Does anyone know of a good encrypt function that only outputs numbers 0-9 and letters a-z or A-Z?  Additionally, I'm looking for a decrypt function to complement the encrypt function so I can actually use it.

I'm not looking for something super secure here.  Just a way to mask the actual tracking token so the user can't change it on their own.

Comment: Take a look at base64. It uses two more characters but that shouldn't be a problem for emails. Maybe combine it with whatever encryption you like.

Comment: you shouldn't need 2 way encryption, just store the (random) token in the db

Comment: @rtfm Yes, that's probably the most sensible thing. Deleting my comment.

Comment: @rtfm: Unless the db is already populated.  Might be much more work.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 should be fine in any modern system - and any system handling email in PHP fits the definition of "modern". There is absolutely no reason I can think of to limit to just alphanumerics. The only catch is that as a URL parameter you don't want to have a '+' or '/' in the string. There is base64url to solve this problem but that doesn't have a standard PHP function. You can easily replicate that by using base64_encode() and str_replace() and to decode str_replace followed by base64_decode():

```
$coded = str_replace('+','-',str_replace('/','_',base64_encode($original)));

$original = base64_decode(str_replace('_','/',str_replace('-','+',$coded)));
```